# Expression trees and lazy evaluation in C#

Tags: c#, lazy-evaluation, expression-trees

I have this little bit of code where I take a `ParameterExpression` array of strings and convert a particular index to a target type. I do this either by calling `Parse` (if the type is primitive) or by attempting a raw conversion (hopefully to a string or implicit string).

```
static Expression ParseOrConvert(ParameterExpression strArray, ConstantExpression index, ParameterInfo paramInfo)
{
    Type paramType = paramInfo.ParameterType;

    Expression paramValue = Expression.ArrayIndex(strArray, index);

    if (paramType.IsPrimitive) {
        MethodInfo parseMethod = paramType.GetMethod("Parse", new[] { typeof(string) });
        // Fetch Int32.Parse(), etc.

        // Parse paramValue (a string) to target type
        paramValue = Expression.Call(parseMethod, paramValue);
    }
    else {
        // Else attempt a raw conversion
        paramValue = Expression.Convert(paramValue, paramType);
    }

    return paramValue;
}
```

This works, but I'm trying to rewrite the conditional as such.

```
paramValue = Expression.Condition(
    Expression.Constant(paramType.IsPrimitive),
    Expression.Call(parseMethod, paramValue),
    Expression.Convert(paramValue, paramType)
);
```

This always results in `System.InvalidOperationException`, presumably because it attempts both conversions. I find the second style more intuitive to write in so this is unfortunate.

Can I write this in a way that defers evaluation to when the values are actually needed?

Comment: What are `paramType`, `paramValue`, `parseMethod` etc. Too many unknowns. Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Full context is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50900034/dynamic-constructor-in-c-sharp, although it's not really this specific problem I'm trying to solve and more a general question.

Comment: You still need to provide some example code, and that is not a link to another question.

Comment: Made it better. :D

Comment: It’s not more intuitive as "if" and Expression.Condition are two entirely different things. The latter would generate code as if you had written the following code `x.GetType().IsPrimitive ? SomeType.Parse(x) : (SomeType)x` which obviously gives a syntax error if SomeType has no proper Parse method. Everything constructed with the expression syntax can be seen as source code in another language, so it must be syntactically valid within this domain. If you want to make your `if` concise just replace it with the `?` operator.

Comment: Side note - more intuitive in this particular case is to use [Expression.Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353516(v=vs.110).aspx) overload accepting optional `MethodInfo`, e.g. `paramValue = Expression.Convert(paramValue, paramType, paramType.IsPrimitive ? paramType.GetMethod("Parse", new[] { typeof(string) }) : null);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressions represent code as data, the true and false branches are not being evaluated here; it is not "attempting both conversions". Instead, it is trying to build an Expression Tree that represents each conversion. The condition however, being a `Constant`, is being baked into the conditional eagerly based on the type.

You are building an expression with the following structure:

```
var result = true // <`true` or `false` based on the type T> 
    ? T.Parse(val)
    : (T) val;
```

When `T` is `int` (and thus the "Test" is the constant `true`) this does not compile because there is no valid cast from `string` to `int`, even though at runtime it would always evaluate/execute `int.Parse(val)`.

When `T` is `Foo`, this would compile when `Foo` has both a static `Parse(string val)` method, and an explicit cast operator

```
public class Foo
{
    public static Foo Parse(string fooStr)
    {
        return default(Foo);
    }

    public static explicit operator Foo(string fooStr)
    {
        return default(Foo);
    }
}
```

Even though it would only ever execute the explicit cast operator because `Foo` is not primitive.

Your original code actually already builds an Expression that will use the "correct"  conversion strategy based on `T` without trying to compile/evaluate the other one. If this isn't working for you already, I suspect it's because the types involved don't have an explicit cast defined from `string`.

As an aside, I would discourage reusing `paramValue` as both the original (unconverted) and converted value, it makes debugging much harder than it needs to be, among other things.

Answer (score 2):

Often debugging is like journalism... In journalism there are the [five Ws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Ws): *who*, *what*, *where*, *when*, *why* (plus *how*).. and in programming it is similar. *who* throws the exception (that is the *what*)? Let's make the code more easy to debug:

```
static Expression ParseOrConvert(ParameterExpression strArray, ConstantExpression index, ParameterInfo paramInfo)
{
    Type paramType = paramInfo.ParameterType;

    Expression paramValue = Expression.ArrayIndex(strArray, index);
    MethodInfo parseMethod = paramType.GetMethod("Parse", new[] { typeof(string) });

    var isPrimitive = Expression.Constant(paramType.IsPrimitive);
    var call = Expression.Call(parseMethod, paramValue);
    var convert = Expression.Convert(paramValue, paramType);

    var paramValue2 = Expression.Condition(
        isPrimitive,
        call,
        convert
    );

    return paramValue2;
}
```

And then call it like:

```
public static void MyMethod(int par1)
{
}
```

and then

```
ParameterExpression strArray = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string[]));

// paramType int
var paramInfo = typeof(Program).GetMethod("MyMethod").GetParameters()[0];

var result = ParseOrConvert(strArray, Expression.Constant(0), paramInfo);
```

Now... *who* throws the exception? `Expression.Convert(paramValue, paramType)` throws an exception... And *why*? Because you are trying to do a:

```
string paramValue = ...;
convert = (int)paramValue;
```

That is surely illegal! Even "dead" code (code that can't be reached) must be "compilable" in .NET (in its IL language). So your error is trying to introduce some illegal dead code in your expression, that would be:

```
string paramValue = ...;
isPrimitive = true ? int.Parse(paramValue) : (int)paramValue;
```

This wouldn't compile in C# and probably can't even be written in IL code. And the Expression classes throw on it.